# Can I use root mean square(RMS) to calculate volatility of intraday feed data?

Tags: volatility

I've been using standard deviation as a direct/simple approach to calculate volatility of a given intraday feed data. My question is it logical/sensible that using root mean square (RMS), which is the square root of mean of squared return as an estimation of volatility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used if your intra day data has a mean very close to 0.
$$
\sigma=\sqrt{E(x^2)-E(x)^2}
$$
if we have $$E(x) \approx 0 \Rightarrow E(x)^2 \approx 0$$
then 
$$ \sigma = \sqrt{E(x^2)}$$